# Updating msql methods with PDO

Tags: php, mysql

I used to use PHP quite a lot some years ago, and have recently decided to update my skills and I am trying to build a forum website, I am specifically having problems using the new PDO method of inserting data gathered from a user back into the table. The code I had using the old mysql methods (which I understand were depracated as of version 5.5 of PHP) is

```
$sql = "INSERT INTO
                    users(user_name, user_pass, user_email ,user_date, user_level)
                VALUES('" . mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['user_name']) . "',
                       '" . sha1($_POST['user_pass']) . "',
                       '" . mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['user_email']) . "',
                        NOW(),
                        0)";

        $result = mysql_query($sql);
        if(!$result)
        {
            //something went wrong, display the error
            echo 'Something went wrong while registering. Please try again later.';
            //echo mysql_error(); //debugging purposes, uncomment when needed
        }
        else
        {
            echo 'Successfully registered. You can now <a href="signin.php">sign in</a> and start posting! :-)';
        }
    }
}
```

Looking up the equivalent PDO method I get this code

```
<?php
    $stmt = $db->prepare("INSERT INTO table(field1,field2,field3,field4,field5) VALUES(:field1,:field2,:field3,:field4,:field5)");
    $stmt->execute(array(':field1' => $field1, ':field2' => $field2, ':field3' => $field3, ':field4' => $field4, ':field5' => $field5));
    $affected_rows = $stmt->rowCount();
```

And so putting the two together I get this (or at least I think I do)

```
$stmt = $db - > prepare("INSERT INTO users(user_name, user_pass, user_email, user_date, user_level) 
                VALUES('" . ($_POST['user_name ']) . "','" . sha1($_POST['user_pass ']) . "','" . ($_POST['user_email ']) . "',NOW(),0)");
$stmt - > execute(array(':user_name' => $user_name, ':user_pass' => $user_pass, ':user_email' => $user_email, ':user_date' => $user_date, ':user_level' => $user_level));
//$affected_rows = $stmt->rowCount();
if (!$result) {
    //something went wrong, display the error
    echo 'Something went wrong while registering. Please try again later.';
    //echo mysql_error(); //debugging purposes, uncomment when needed
} else {
    echo 'Successfully registered. You can now <a href="signin.php">sign in</a> and start posting! :-)';
}
```

However when I run it, I get a series of 'Undefined variable' errors for each field that I try to update

My hosting provider does allow me to run the old code with a now unsupported PHP version but I believe this to be unsafe and vulnerable to SQL injection, so as part of the (re)learning experience I thought I would try and figure out the new way of doing things.

Any help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: Please don't use sha1 for password storage. Use `password_hash()` instead

Comment: Thanks, so noted... I'll change that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're trying to apply prepared statements but doing it the wrong way this is what you need to have:

```
$user_name = $_POST['user_name'];
$user_pass = password_hash($_POST['user_pass'], PASSWORD_BCRYPT);
$user_email = $_POST['user_email'];
$user_date = time();
$user_level = 0;
$stmt = $db->prepare("INSERT INTO
                    users(user_name, user_pass, user_email ,user_date, user_level)
               VALUES(:user_name, :user_pass, :user_email, :user_date, :user_level)");
        $stmt->execute(array(':user_name' => $user_name, ':user_pass' => $user_pass, ':user_email' => $user_email, ':user_date' => $user_date, ':user_level' => $user_level));
        //$affected_rows = $stmt->rowCount();
        if(!$result)
        {
            //something went wrong, display the error
            echo 'Something went wrong while registering. Please try again later.';
            //echo mysql_error(); //debugging purposes, uncomment when needed
        }
        else
        {
            echo 'Successfully registered. You can now <a href="signin.php">sign in</a> and start posting! :-)';
        }
```

The execute statement binds each key in the array with the corresponding placeholder in the query. You might also want to do some research on the password hash function

Comment: Thanks everyone, that worked, save for a little syntax to get it to work with the rest of the code.